# ACF custom field type not appearing on backend - jQuery error on ion range slider

Tags: jquery, advanced-custom-fields, rangeslider, ion-range-slider

Wordpress and ACF custom field type.

I've been trying to use the [ACF custom field type plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-new-field-type/) to add an [ion range slider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/index.html), (including on the front end form) I get a jQuery error and the slider just displays as an empty text field.

It throws a different error depending on whether the function is referenced from the front end (on a form) or the backend (admin console). This is the basic code:

```
        <script>
    
    min=            "<?php echo $field['min'] ?>",   
    max=            "<?php echo $field['max'] ?>",  
    type=           "<?php echo $field['handles'] ?>",
    skin=           "<?php echo $field['skin'] ?>",
    step=           "<?php echo $field['step'] ?>",
    from=           "<?php echo $field['from'] ?>",
    to=             "<?php echo $field['to'] ?>";
    
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();    
    j$(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
        type:type,
        skin:skin,
        min:min,
        max:max,
        step:step,
        from:from,
        to:to
    });
    
    </script>
```

The back end works (i.e the range slider appears on the admin console.) But on the front end (a form input) it throws and error

[image: Console]

I'm not in any sense JQuery coder so this has me stumped. Do the JQuery gurus have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a issue with the acf plugin template. The path statements for enqueuing scripts are poorly done. Recoded them and now its all working great.

On the front end

[image]

and on the back end..

[image]